# iPad application to generate a report

Tags: ios, ipad, email

I am trying to create an iPad application which has a FORM, after entering the data, when I save, the data needs to be generated as a report and sent as an email to whomever is required (the email is entered in the FORM). I want to know if this can be achieved without using web service . What is the flow in this case? Can the email client on iPad be used for this purpose?

Comment: "without using ??" What?  If this is your homework, please include all of the homework question and mark the question with the [homework] tag.

Comment: Actually it can be achieved just by using ?? no need of ???

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use an `MFMailComposeViewController` to display the interface for sending an email. You can pass your data to this view controller's `messageBody` property as an NSString. See the documentation for details.

The email message can also include an attachment (a PDF or any other file available to the app) using the `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` method of the `MFMailComposeViewController` object. In this particular case, you'd draw the form to a PDF document. Start with the *Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS* in Apple's documentation for details.

Comment: Thank you Berna,
I would want to send the Report as an attachment . say as a PDF file format . Can we achieve that ?

Comment: Thank you Berna ..much appreciated ..Hema